# How to change Power button shutdown action

Tags: linux, shutdown, power-management, acpi

I use Mageia ver 4 Linux as server, without X started and without any user login-in during normal operation. This PC has a special card for measuring and control of other devices. This card has its own SH4 Linux on-board, and needs to be shutdown first, before PC shutdown.

There is a set of commands supplied by the card vendor and they works properly. To shutdown the card it is necessary to execute `/usr/sbin/io_card stop`, wait for proper card shutdown and then execute "ordinary" PC shutdown.

I wrote a special shutdown script and it works properly.
But the problem is when I press "Power" button on PC, it executes "ordinary" PC shutdown instead of my script.

I try to change /etc/acpi/events/power and systemd scripts to include my own shutdown script, but it does not work. At this moment /etc/acpi/events/power file contains only entry :

```
action=/home/serwer/Pobrane/shut
```

where "shut" is my shutdown script, working good when running manually.
So how can I change default power-off action associated with depressing "Power" button?

Comment: Please explain exactly _how_ you tried to change ` /etc/acpi/events/power`.

Comment: The /etc/acpi/events/power file contains only entry action=/home/serwer/Pobrane/shut where "shut" is my shutdown script, working good when running manually.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Also, please [edit] your question to add new info, it is easy to miss and hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee this will work on Mageia but this is how I got a similar thing to work on my Debian.

There is a script (on my machine, it's `/etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh`) that is run by default when the power button is pressed. Edit that script, and find this section:

```
if [ -x /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh ] ; then
    # Compatibility with old config script from acpid package
    /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
elif [ -x /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.dpkg-bak ] ; then
        # Compatibility with old config script from acpid package
    # which is still around because it was changed by the admin
        /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.dpkg-bak
else
    # Normal handling.
    /sbin/shutdown -h -P now "Power button pressed"

fi
```

Change `/sbin/shutdown -h -P now "Power button pressed"` to point to your script instead, save the file and that should now be launched whenever you press the power button.

Comment: May /etc/acpi subdir contains two dirs: "action" and "events". So it is a little bit different to Yours

Comment: OK, I edited my post. At this moment I de facto use the same solution as You described in Your post. The only diffrence is that in Your instalation, shutdown script is located in /etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh, in my Linux distro default location is /etc/acpi/events/power file. And this one was edited by me as described.

Answer (score 0):

If you have polkit version >= 0.106, you can set a polkit rule file, linked to shutdown action, which calls your script when the user press shutdown button.

The polkit rule will be similar to this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop" ||
    action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
    action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" || 
    action.id == "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper")  
{
        polkit.spawn(["/home/serwer/Pobrane/shut", subject.user]);        
        return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});
```

To add this rule, you only have to copy this in a file with .rules extension, and copy the file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/`

But I don't know if this runs without a graphical interface